# Overstay in Serbia

Tags: overstaying, covid-19, serbia

I'm almost at the end of my permission to stay in Serbia legally. I've heard stories that people went over the Bosnian border and then came back to Serbia during the three years period (UK nationality). They might stamp the passport or not. But they didn't check the old stamps if overstayed.

My personal view of it all is that the border crossings do not care at all. But airport checks. And that if you do it the legal way, it will be more problems going through their bureaucracy.

Someone else has some insight if this could be possible to overstay during a long period of time? What could be the consequences?

Comment: Other than being fined or possibly banned from the country?

Comment: In general, visa overstays can become a problem, and should be avoided if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you, as a UK citizen, plan to stay longer than 90 days in Serbia within a 6 month period then you should apply for temporary residence status. It is recommended that this is done at least 30 days before the 90 day period expires.

You can find more information here:

http://www.london.mfa.gov.rs/consularservicestext.php?subaction=showfull&id=1348565352&ucat=17&template=MeniENG&

And here:

http://www.mfa.gov.rs/en/

Answer (score 0):

Serbia does prosecute, imprison and deport illegal immigrants, which is what you will be once the 90 days are up.

Now that traffic to/from Serbia is up and running once more, it's no longer possible to obtain an exceptional residence permit.

So you need to exit on time, and make sure to get stamped (unless using an ID card, which most Swedes don't).